# Show that $\rho$ satisfies triangle inequality.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, triangle-inequality

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open set and $K \subseteq G$ be compact. Let $(\Omega,d)$ be a metric space and $C(G,\Omega)$ be the space of all continuous functions from $G$ to $\Omega.$ Define a function $\rho : C(G,\Omega) \times C(G,\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$\rho (f,g) = \sup\limits \{d(f(z),g(z))\ |\ z \in K\}$$ $f,g \in C(G,\Omega).$ Show that $\rho$ satisfies triangle inequality i.e. for any $f,g,h \in C(G,\Omega)$ we have $$\rho (f,g) + \rho (g,h) \geq \rho (f,h).$$

I have tried to approach in the following way $:$

We have for any $f,g,h \in C(G,\Omega)$ $$\begin{align*} \rho (f,g) + \rho (g,h) & = \sup\limits \{d(f(z),g(z))\ |\ z \in K\} + \sup\limits \{d(g(z),h(z))\ |\ z \in K\} \\ & = \sup\limits \{d(f(z),g(z)) + d(g(z'),h(z')) \ |\ z,z' \in K\} \\ & \geq \sup\limits \{d(f(z),g(z)) + d(g(z),h(z))\ |\ z \in K\} \\ & \geq \sup\limits \{d(f(z),h(z))\ |\ z \in K\} \\ & = \rho (f,h) \end{align*}$$

Is it fine what I did or should I add something more to it? Please verify it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: On line 2 of your proof when you combine the two $\sup$ to 1, somehow the $h$ function disappears?

Comment: What you have done is correct if you drop the second equality.

Comment: @Alan fixed it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir that was a typo. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. However, it can be simplified. For example, the equality
$$
\sup\{d(f(z),g(z))\ |\ z \in K\} + \sup\{d(g(z),h(z))\ |\ z \in K\} \\  = \sup\limits \{d(f(z),g(z)) + d(g(z'),h(z')) \ |\ z,z' \in K\}
$$
is true but requires some thinking. On the other hand, you need only $\ge$, which is easier to verify.

I would write it as follows: For all $z \in K$ is
$$
 d(f(z), h(z)) \le d(f(z), g(z)) + d(g(z), h(z)) \le \rho(f, g) + \rho(g, h)
$$
and since the right-hand side does not depend on $z$, $\rho(f, g) \le \rho(f, g) + \rho(g, h)$ follows. This is more or less equivalent to your calculation, but easier to read in my opinion.